# Slide tool in hair sculpt mode

Tags: modeling

I am using blender 4.0.2 and "new hair system". There is a slide tool in the sculpt mode for hair curves. But every time I try to use it, my hair curves jumps back to their original place...

[image]

Comment: Are you able to share some screenshots to show us what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Onyx sure, post edited

Comment: Same problem, the slide tool never work for me. So I just move the vertices in edit mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a tablet with pen pressure? I had the same problem until I disabled the "strength pressure" button right beside the strength slider.

Comment: TY so much! Who would have thought... Seems like a bug.